# Meteor MongoDB aggregate - Collapsing certain values to 'Others'

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework

I am working on a toy project with Meteor and MongoDB to learn how to use them.

The MongoDB documents have a pretty simple structure:

```
{athlete: "Michael Jordan", brand: "Nike"}
{athlete: "Shaquille O'Neal", brand: "Reebok"}
```

etc..

I want to publish the number of athletes associated with a given brand to a D3.js method to create a piechart. This is easy to do.

The trouble I am having is with collecting brands below a certain threshold (in the example below, brands with only one athlete) into a single row to pass to the client. For example, if the brand distribution is:

```
{_id: "Nike", count:4} {_id: "Reebok",count:5} {_id: "Puma",count:3}{_id:"Adidas",count:1} {_id:"New Balance", count:1} {_id:"Under Armour", count:1}
```

I want the output to be:

```
{_id: "Nike", count:4} {_id: "Reebok",count:5} {_id: "Puma",count:3}{_id:"Others",count:3}
```

Here is the code I have tried:

```
pipeline = [
      {$group:{
        _id: "$brand",
        count: {$sum: 1}
      }},
      {$project:{
        _id:{
          $cond:[ { $eq: [ "$count", 1 ] }, 'Others', "$_id" ]
        },
        count:{
          $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$count", 1 ] },{$sum:"$count"}, "$count"]
        }
      }}
      ];
```

The _id condition does collapse the single entry brands into 'Others'. If the _id attribute is the only thing passed, I can see the expected results in the browser console (List of  brands with more than 1 athletes and Others).

To get the count, I have tried three things:

1. Setting the true condition in the count if to `{$sum:"$count"}` as
   above
2. Setting the true condition in the count if to `{$sum:1}`
3. Setting count to a non-conditional `{$sum:"$count"}`

All three result in an empty array being passed to the client. Any ideas on how to get this to work?

---

Solution:
Setting the pipeline as follows does what I described as desired behaviour in the previous section.

```
pipeline = [
      {$group:{
        _id: "$brand",
        count: {$sum: 1}
      }},
      {$group:{
        _id:{
          $cond:[ { $eq: [ "$count", 1 ] }, 'Others', "$_id"]
        },
     count:{$sum:"$count"}
      }}
      ];
```

Comment: How large is the collection? If it's small, the easiest solution is just to send the whole thing to the client and let a helper do the aggregation. If it's large, it may be worth keeping the aggregated data in a separate collection.

Comment: David, thanks for your response. I did consider going the client route as my collection is indeed small. However, I was able to get what I wanted to work on the server, which is what I preferred. My solution is in my original comment if anyone is interested.